# SQLite strange behavior

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to retrieve a particular cell from a table. I want alarm_music(TEXT) where I have the hours(INTEGER) and the minutes(INTEGER)(In the where clause) of the alarm stored in the alarm table. 
code where the query is fired

```
mBhelperClass = new AlarmsDBhelperClass(this);
        db= mBhelperClass.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours="+hour+" AND minutes="+min,null);
        Log.d("gaurnagSnooze",""+cursor.getCount());
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            songPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlarmsDBhelperClass.MUSIC_PATH));
            Log.d("if executed! ","songpath initialized!");
        }
        cursor.close();
```

**the moveToFirst() returns FALSE meaning no rows in the table.**  
but when I fire `SELECT musicPath FROM alarms` the moveToFirst() returns **TRUE**.
how is this possible?

Comment: are you sure the content is in the table ?

Comment: it's now working I don't know what's wrong with android studio

Comment: it's not working again!!!

Comment: can someone plz help me

Comment: in what way is it not working ?

Comment: same problem(cursor returning no rows). but I noticed a strange behavior when I run SELECT * FROM alarms the query works fine and even returns a cursor with rows!. but if I run the above query. I get moveToFirst() as FALSE which means no rows! how's this even possible? is there something wrong with the syntax I've used?

Comment: *how is this possible?* it is possible if there are no rows for the conditions in the WHERE clause. Use Android Studio's Device File Explorer to extract the DB from the device from the folder: `/data/data/<yourpackagename>/databases/` and inspect the table. Then run the code with the WHERE clause by supplying values to the variables `hour` and `min` that you are sure that exist in the table.

Comment: I did, I found the problem is in the physical device. the database shows some dump values on its first installation(another reason for my app crashing) and the tables are sometimes even deleted! from the device. but the same works fine on an emulator.

Comment: In some devices, there is a backup service. They try to restore application data when they notice the new app installation. Check with `allowBackup="false"` option in your manifest

Comment: ThankYou @BakhtiyorBegmatov for the suggestion. worked for me!

Comment: So can I take this bounty? :)

Comment: it was one of the errors I was getting. the main issue still persists!

Answer (score 6):

Problem: The cursor.moveToFirst() returned **FALSE** meaning no Rows existing.
Solution: While inserting rows in the table I used a **24hour** clock format Calendar's instance from the time picker and stored in the table. But when I tried to retrieve the value from the database using hours as the where clause I used **12Hour** clock format Calendar's instance. which would for sure yield no output hence no rows returned as cursor and cursor.moveToFirst() returning FLASE.

Answer (score 2):

This query is unsafe it may result on unwanted result. However, if you want to use unsafe mode change below query

```
"SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours="+hour+" AND minutes="+min
```

To

```
"SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours= '"+hour+"' AND minutes= '"+min+"'"
```

add `'` around the `whereArgs`.

Although it's correct but it's not recommended(**unsafe**)

it's recommended(**safe**) to include `?` in `where clause` in the `query` and replace them by values from `where args`.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours = ? AND minutes = ? ",new String[]{hour,min});
```

Comment: The query: `"SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours="+hour+" AND minutes="+min` is **not** wrong because the columns `hours` and `minutes` are `INTEGER`.

Comment: @forpas yea it's integer but when you are trying to insert whereArges in the query directly it's recommended to add `'` around the values in SQLITE.

Comment: @forpas in the sqlite there is no difference between string and int.

Comment: What is whereArges? It is not recommended to use single quotes for an integer column. It is recommended to use `?` placeholders. So the OP's query is **not** wrong.

Comment: @forpas actually i should edit the answer . i didn't mean actually it's wrong i mean it's  unsafe.

Comment: It is not more unsafe without single quotes than with single quotes.

Comment: @forpas i read a confident document about it and i would share to you .

Comment: hey, @forpas I finally found the problem, I stored the hours in my table in a 24hour Clock format(c.HOUR_OF_DAY). and in my where clause I tried to retrieve using a 12hour Clock format calendar instance(c.HOUR). can you please forgive me! I wasted your precious time.

Comment: lastly whom to give this bounty?

Comment: Post an answer where you explain what the problem was and how you solved it and then accept it. As for the bounty it will expire.

Comment: @RaunakPandey answer to your own question. and don't consider passing it to me

Comment: I'm extremely sorry Sir!

Comment: Okay doing wait

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this answer **will not help** with your problem, but I hope it will help you with the code style.

You can interface like this for all you select queries

```java
public interface SelectQuery {

    Cursor execute(SQLiteDatabase db);
}
```

And here your query's implementation by this interface

```java
public class MusicPathsByHoursAndMinutesQuery implements SelectQuery {

    private static final String TAG = MusicPathsByHoursAndMinutesQuery.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String PRECOMPILED_QUERY_STATEMENT =
            "SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours = ? and minutes = ?";

    private final int hours;
    private final int minutes;

    public MusicPathsByHoursAndMinutesQuery(int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor execute(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(PRECOMPILED_QUERY_STATEMENT, getQueryArgs());

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Query: " + PRECOMPILED_QUERY_STATEMENT);
            Log.d(TAG, "With args: " + Arrays.toString(getQueryArgs()));
            Log.d(TAG, "Returned cursor with " + cursor.getCount() + " rows.");
        }

        return cursor;
    }

    private String[] getQueryArgs() {
        return new String[]{
                String.valueOf(hours),
                String.valueOf(minutes)
        };
    }
}
```

And its usage (logging also enabled in debug mode)

```java
Cursor cursor = new MusicPathsByHoursAndMinutesQuery(hours, minutes).execute(db);
```

Answer (score 0):

try  select all

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE 1=1",null);

then create your where clause like some body mentioned

your query was wrong

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours="+hour+" AND minutes="+min,null);
as min was not inside double quote +min
```

you could have done this

```
   String sql = "SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours="+hour+" AND minutes="+min + " ;";

 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT musicPath FROM alarms WHERE hours = ? AND minutes = ? ",new String[]{hour,min});
```

Sample:

```
try (Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                    "select * from " + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_USER +
                            " where " + SQLiteHelper.USER_CLM_REVOKE_TX_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{revokeTxId})) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return createUserChannelFromCursor(cursor);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
```